# Multiple Session not working in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
$this->session->set_userdata('logged_in', $sess_array);
$session_data = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
$id = $session_data['user_id'];
$value = $this->m_login->userPermission($id);
$this->session->set_userdata('permission_value',$value);
$reports = $this->m_login->userPermissionReports($id);
$this->session->set_userdata('reports',$reports);
```

The last session i.e (`$reports`) is not created, why?
please help me?

Comment: Those are not multiple sessions, but multiple values stored in the same session. Multiple sessions would imply multiple cookies and several session IDs and likely a completely different problem.

Comment: Very rare cases requires that structure of sessions to store. Instead, store references such as ID and fetch the data on relevant pages.

Comment: please first check what does your variable $reports contain..... may be you are getting null value in it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mr Faizan Khattak There are only one session but you have to set multiple session value on that session.

```
 $this->session->set_userdata('reports',$reports);
 $this->session->set_userdata('reports_new',$reports);
```

Something like that!!!!!

Comment: Mr Dev
  i create user_loggin and permission_value session it work
when create reports session it not created and do not show me the vales

Answer (score 1):

Unless you are saving session data to a database you could have a problem. I have no idea how much data you are trying to insert into the session. But..

4kb of data is the maximum size a cookie can hold.